# Object nulled when cast into type

Tags: c#, generics, types, null

This is my code

```
public virtual T GetRepository<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        var type = typeof ( T );
        var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach ( var property in properties )
        {
            var name = property.Name;
            if ( name == type.Name )
            {
                var a = this.GetType().GetProperty(name) as T;
                return a;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The objective is to return the generic type T. First I get the properties of the class, and then I loop over the properties in hopes of finding a property name which has the same name as the type T.

This works okay in my case because the properties are all of the form `Interface<FooRepository> FooRepository { get; set; }` so I need only compare the two.

This method is inside a class. The problem is that `a` will change to `null` immediately after the statement `as T`. What can be done?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to call this method at runtime to return the uniquely-determined property of type T inside the class.

Comment: You probably intend to get the value of the property, so you want something like `return property.GetValue(this, null) as T;`

Comment: Please provide [MCVE]. It is very unclear what you trying to achieve (even with your comment) and why you think it should work.

Comment: So you want to return property value which is equal to type `T` ? Did I understood you well? What if there are two properties with same type?

Comment: I define the class such that that doesn't happen. The types are implementations of interfaces, so they are easy to define as unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the value of the property you could try using the [`GetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx) method and replace this:

```
var a = this.GetType().GetProperty(name) as T;
```

with this:

```
var a = property.GetValue(this) as T;
```

Also it is not quite clear what exactly is the purpose of such method but this condition here looks shaky:

```
if (name == type.Name)
```

The name of the property should equal the name of the generic type parameter. Is it really what is needed here?

Comment: This works, thanks sir! I'll mark the answer when it lets me.

Comment: @Johnath now when you know the answer, please figure out what you wanted to ask and update your question so future visitors can find it when facing similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

GetProperty method will always return ProprtyInfo type so unless T is PropertyInfo a will be always null.

Comment: Oh, ok. Do you know of any approaches? I'm all out of ideas. Can I get the actual property from within those variables?

Comment: Try it like @darin-dimitrov wrote in comments. :-)